# How does the GitLab API approve merge requests?

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I tried using `POST /projects/xx/merge_requests/xx/approve` requests. After requesting the request, returned `"message": "401 Unauthorized"`,I also added the request header `PRIVATE-TOKEN`。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure (as documented in [GitLab Merge Requests Approvals](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/)) that:

- you have "Developer" or greater [permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) to approve merge requests
- the project does not have defined specific rules, like  a list of users who act as code owners for specific files: only members of that list would have the right to approve a PR.
- you have checked if [the project require password to approve](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/settings.html#require-user-password-to-approve), which means you need to pass the `approval_password` parameter

Second, the curl call would be of the form ([GitLab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#approve-merge-request))

```
curl -XPOST "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_PROJECT_ID/merge_requests/$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID/notes" \
      -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $MR_TOKEN" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
      --data-urlencode 'sha=<sha>&approval_password=<password>'
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                          (only if the project requires it)
```

With `sha` matching the current HEAD of the merge request for the approval to be added.

Comment: I checked the approval rules and found no approval rules. They are empty
```projects/xx/merge_requests/xx/approval_rules```
eventuate
```[]```

Comment: @YuSheng OK. Does the curl I mention work?

Comment: Hello, I would like to know how to obtain the sha parameter value you mentioned before？

Comment: @YuSheng It is the most recent commit of your PR branch.

Comment: Thanks. The problem has been solved。

Comment: @YuSheng Well done!